# Calculating the RMS angle of a driven oscillator

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

We are given that the oscillator obeys the following DE: $\ddot{\theta} + \omega_0^2\theta = \text{cos}(\omega t)$. The solution is $\theta = Ae^{i\omega_0t} + Be^{-i\omega_0t} + \frac{\text{cos}(\omega t)}{\omega_0^2 - \omega^2}$. Using the fact (given to us in the problem) that the oscillator is at rest at t = 0, we have that $\theta = 2A\text{cos}(\omega_0 t) + \frac{\text{cos}(\omega t)}{\omega_0^2 - \omega^2}$.

Here is where I am stuck. The question then asks us to find the RMS angle of the oscillator. I know that this requires us to evaluate $\theta^2$ and integrate it between $t = 0$ and $t = \frac{2\pi}{\omega_0}$. We are also allowed to assume that the average is taken over a time much larger than $\frac{1}{\mid \omega_0 - \omega\mid}$. (I don't really know what this means). I ended up with this expression:

$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{T}\theta^2 dt = \frac{1}{2(\omega_0^2 - \omega^2)^2}(\frac{\text{sin}(2\omega T)}{2\omega} + T) - \frac{4\omega A\text{sin}(\omega T)} {(\omega_0^2 - \omega^2)^2} + 2A^2T$ (where $T = \frac{2\pi}{\omega_0}$).

Now, I'm not even sure if I have evaluated the integral properly but I would like to know how I am supposed to use the previously mentioned assumption that they have provided in the question. Also, the question says that the oscillator (which is a pendulum) is in equilibrium at $t = 0$ - does this mean that $\theta = 0$ at $t = 0$? This would give $A = \frac{1}{2(\omega_0^2 - \omega^2)}$. We are also supposed to discuss the motion as $\mid \omega_0 - \omega\mid \rightarrow 0$. Can anyone help?

Comment: as you have defined it above $\theta$ is not the phase angle of the oscillator thus its mean square will not get you the rms angle

Answer (score 1):

The expression you use for the RMS angle,
$$
\theta_\mathrm{rms}^2=\frac 1T\int_0^T\theta(t)^2\mathrm dt,
$$
is only valid for a periodic function, with period $T$. Your solution is not periodic, since there is in general no expected relationship between the two frequencies $\omega$ and $\omega_0$, so that expression is not really valid.

In these cases the correct expression is the long-time limit of the average,
$$
\theta_\mathrm{rms}^2=\lim_{T\to\infty}\frac 1T\int_0^T\theta(t)^2\mathrm dt,
$$
which is insensitive to edge effects.

Regarding the $\omega\to\omega_0$ limit, it should be evident that your solution breaks down at the limit itself. However, there are standard tools for solving the equation of motion in that case (e.g. [here](http://www.jirka.org/diffyqs/htmlver/diffyqsse15.html)). How does the behaviour change in the resonant case? How with this square with the limit of the $\theta_\mathrm{rms}$ you found previously when you take $\omega\to\omega_0$?